# Will Karma be updated for future versions of Angular and Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, testing, jasmine

I tried updating our companies Angular module, with that comes the required dependencies update. So I went to all the newest versions. Which included jasmine-core 5.0.0. This broke our Jasmine-karma-HTML-Reporter, since version 2.0.0 is the last of Jasmine-karma-HTML-Reporter versions since 1 year. That version relies on Jasmine-core 4.x.x, this made me look into all the other karma dependencies. And I found out that a lot, if not all, of the karma packages haven't been getting updates since 1 year or more.
So what I am trying to figure out is if these will be getting updates or if there are any similar other packages. If we have to migrate it, we would love as little change as possible. Also we would like to keep the configurability that we had with the karma.config, does something like this exist?

We want to update to Angular 16, with all the newest versions.
Currently I went back down to Jasmine-core 4.6.0, but this cant be the long term solution. I went to the corresponding NPM post of all the karma packages.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. [Karma is deprecated and is not accepting new features or general bug fixes](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma#karma-is-deprecated-and-is-not-accepting-new-features-or-general-bug-fixes):

> The web testing space has evolved significantly in the [10+ years](https://testing.googleblog.com/2012/11/testacular-spectacular-test-runner-for.html) since Karma's creation. The web landscape looks very different today and new patterns and tools have emerged in the ecosystem. New test runners offer more performant alternatives, and Karma no longer provides clear unique value.
>
> Based on the current state of the web testing ecosystem, we have made the hard decision to deprecate Karma.
>
> We know Karma is used particularly commonly in the Angular ecosystem, so Angular is adding [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and [Web Test Runner](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/overview/) support to provide a migration path off of Karma. See the [Angular blog](https://blog.angular.io/moving-angular-cli-to-jest-and-web-test-runner-ef85ef69ceca) for more details.
>
> Critical security issues in Karma will still be triaged and fixed as necessary. This will continue until 12 months after Angular CLI's Web Test Runner support is marked stable.
>
> For those outside Angular looking to migrate off Karma, both [Web Test Runner](https://modern-web.dev/docs/test-runner/overview/) and [`jasmine-browser-runner`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-browser-runner) provide browser-based unit testing solutions which can be used as a direct alternative. [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) and [Vitest](https://vitest.dev/) also provide Node-based alternatives.

Recommending alternatives is strictly outside the scope of StackOverflow, but hopefully the above provides some pointers.